# SQL CASE Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

I need to write a sql statement(Oracle) where I can withdraw data from two diff tables and check for a condition and return a certain string.
My statement goes like this,

```
Select review.comments as comments,resort.resortid,resort.resortname 
case review.comments 
when resort.starrating>=4.5 and resort.starrating<5 then 'Excellent'
when resort.strarating>=4 and resort.starrating<4.5 then 'Great'
else 'Good'
end
from review, resort 
order by resort.resortid;
```

When I run this I get a error: "FROM keyword not found where expected"and points to the c in line 2.
and if I change the from to line 2, it gives error: "SQL command not properly ended". and points to line 3 r in "case review.comments"

Comment: It's a `CASE` expression, not  a function

Comment: Your implicit join is missing a condition to relate both tables. Here, you are doing a cartesian product of both datasets.

Comment: You are missing a comma just before case.

Comment: @Sami Okay. I am new to this. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `JOIN`, aggregation, and to fix the `CASE` expression syntax.  I assume you want something like this:

```
Select res.resortid, res.resortname, 
       (case when avg(rev.starrating) >= 4.5 then 'Excellent'
             when avg(rev.starrating) >= 4 then 'Great'    
            else 'Good'
        end) as category
from review rev join
     resort res
     on rev.resortid = res.resortid
group by res.resortid, res.resortname 
order by res.resortid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two variants of the `case` syntax. If you're going to supply conditions (not just values), you shouldn't have an expression following the `case` keyword:

```sql
case -- review.comments should be removed from here
when resort.starrating>=4.5 and resort.starrating<5 then 'Excellent'
when resort.strarating>=4 and resort.starrating<4.5 then 'Great'
else 'Good'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for `case` is

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

so your code should look like this..

```
SELECT review.comments AS comments, 
           resort.resortid, 
           resort.resortname, 
           CASE
             WHEN resort.starrating >= 4.5 
                  AND resort.starrating < 5 THEN 'Excellent' 
             WHEN resort.strarating >= 4 
                  AND resort.starrating < 4.5 THEN 'Great' 
             ELSE 'Good' 
           END 

    FROM   review, 
               resort 
           ORDER  BY resort.resortid;
```

Also just for your information, The comma between the two tables signifies a `CROSS JOIN`.

So your query is equivalent to:

```
select * from
FROM   review
       CROSS JOIN resort
```